# HUGGINGFACE TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: deep-learning, data-science, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface-datasets

I am working on Fine-Tuning Pretrained Model on custom (using HuggingFace) dataset I will copy all code correctly from the one youtube video everything is ok but in this cell/code:

```
with training_args.strategy.scope():
    model=TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-uncased")

    trainer = TFTrainer(model=model,     # the instantiated  Transformers model to be trained
    args=training_args,                  # training arguments, defined above
    train_dataset=train_dataset,         # training dataset
    eval_dataset=test_dataset)           # evaluation dataset


    trainer.train()
```

It will give me this error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Comment: Perhaps this would be a better fit for an issue on the Huggingface Github.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with the new version of transformers.

Installing version 4.6.0 worked for me.

```
pip install transformers==4.6.0
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me on Google Colab

Answer (score 1):

For people looking for answer at the latest time,
I changed the version of transformers into 4.6.0 and it did not work.

Then, I try to change it to:

```
pip install -q transformers==4.23.1
```

---

And it worked for me.
Hope can help you guys.
(03.01.2023)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I was using setfit library issued by huggingface. The root of this problem was in some rows of my dataset where I had '\r' at the end of a text field, so when I used pd.DataFrame.to_csv(), to_csv() function didn't work well and saved one row literally in two rows like this:

[image]

After all, I had to use pd.DataFrame['specific culomn'].str.strip() for that specific column to remove all '\r'.